# Is there a way to raycast using a curved line in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working with projectiles and I want to know at which point of flight it intersects with an object in the scene. However, the THREE.js raycaster only allows to raycast using a single Vector.

I was wondering if there was a way to use a curved line (parabola), to raycast and see at which point it intersects any object in the scene, so that I know when to stop drawing it?

Comment: You can "draw" a curve along your trajectory use [getSpacedPoints](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/core/Curve.getSpacedPoints) to get points in your curve and check if they collide with any object.

Comment: @Orifjon but wouldn't that be performance heavy?

Comment: It will have performance impacts. You can partially mitigate it by decreasing number of points. Give it a try and see if it works for you.

Comment: Alright, will do